# Search a list by user input using readLine

Tags: kotlin

I would like to search through a list and only return entries that match a queried input using readLine. Following code only works if user types full name that is on the list, while I would like them to be able to enter 's' and retrieve all names with the letter s. Should I use a for loop instead?

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

var names = arrayListOf(
        "Nathan",
        "Gerald",
        "Winchester",
        "Razi",
        "Tetsuo",
        "Bob",
        "Ryandick",
        "Jacafar",
        "Palamov",
        "Zaxon")

    print("Enter search query: ")
    val terms:String? = readLine()!!.toString()
    val output = names.filter{it == terms}
    println(output)
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the filter criterion:

```
val output = names.filter { it.contains(terms) }
```

You can perform case-insensitive matches:

```
val output = names.filter { it.contains(terms, true) }
```